# C# (ADO.NET) Passing variables as constructor parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 forms, categories and products, and they are connected to a data source (database).

The idea is, 
I want the application firstly to load the form categories, which displays some info about the existing categories.

When I click on the button products, the products form  should appear displaying the products of the current selected category name and ID in the categories form

I've done almost the work, but I'm stuck in how pass the values of the category id and name of the categories form to the ones in the products form, and then display the corresponding data,

So far, I created a string variable that takes the value `textbox.text` of the category text box, then I created an object of the categories form in the form products

then I wrote this code, which connects to the database, and selects data from the table "products" where the id is equal to the id of the categories form:

```
Categories cat = new Categories();
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = Northwind40.sdf");
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from products where [Category ID] = '" + cat.currID + "'", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Products");
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(ds, "Products");
this.productsBindingSource = bs;
```

But this code just shows me one result, which is just the first product of the selected category id

So how can I go about this?

Comment: What is `this.productsBindingSource`? To which control is bounded this data? `Form` doesn't show something by itself, it is just container for controls.

Comment: To what you are binding the data? Is it a gridview?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not using the right instance of `Categories` form. You have created a new instance which will not have any ID value in it that user would have selected.

One if the ways would be to have a parameterized constructor in the `Product` form. Then, on the button click event of the Product button in the Category form:

```
Product productForm = new ProductForm("send selected values here");
```

In the Product form constructors,

```
string _selectedValues;
private Product(){
// Code here
}

public Product(string selectedValues):this(){
_selectedValues = selectedValues;
}
```

You can choose the datatype of the parameter as per needs.

Answer (score -1):

This query '`select * from products where [Category ID]...` may returns only one row.
Try replace the following line:

```
 //SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from products where [Category ID] = '" + cat.currID + "'", con);
```

with this line:

```
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from products", con);
```

Be sure there are more than one item for a category.

Comment: This is a test case only. This definitely doesn't solve the problem. Put it as a comment.